# Is there any method which is equivalent to Convert.ToOADate() of VB in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

The method Convert.ToOADate() converts Double data to Date.
Is there any method which is equivalent to this method? or kindly help me a method through which we can convert a double data into a datetime

Comment: What's double data? Do you mean a value stored in a double? Then, which units? Seconds? And what exactly do you want it converted to? NSDate?

Comment: The OADate is the time interval, in *days*, from midnight, 30 Dec 1899. Hours, minutes, seconds etc. are represented as fractions of a day. The OADate is stored as a double.

Comment: Sorry, not midnight, but noon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
    double myDate;
    NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",myDate];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];

    [dateFormat release];
```